# Is it recommended to leave a comment that signatures are removed?

Tags: discussion, edits, comments, signatures, edit-summary

I came through a case today where someone removed a `Thank you in advance!` alike signature from the otherwise long post of the OP. I think the post also had other issues, but those were not fixed. Perhaps, it is just me who only saw those issues.

Anyway, the editor then left a comment writing something along the lines of "Do not put signature into your question as your name is already indicated".

Is this a good practice to do instead of using the `Edit summary` for this purpose? I asked the person and then I was told the OP is new (rep 1) and he may not read the edit history. Still, as far as I can tell, this comment was a distraction from the real topic, which was really interesting by the way.

So, do we need to write such comments for newcomers?

Comment: I'd say these comments are noisy and unnecessary so I'd not advise to leave them.  Including that detail in the edit summary is what that is for.

Comment: Related: [“That's not what the comments are for”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213963/thats-not-what-the-comments-are-for)

Comment: I'd say  just use the edit summary and link to canonical post in there: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242208/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-comments

Comment: I most often leave comments as well on low rep/first posters if I remove tags from titles and edit out signatures

Comment: I think we should write a comment to learn new users how to format their questions (in case they ask more than one question) ... and remove the comment after a while. I'd like to have private or temporary messages for that, but I did not found better than commenting and later remove the comment.

Comment: I can't speak for other, but for me in my first time on SO, such comment allowed me to understand better the way to ask question and was expected to be included and what was not.

Comment: @im_a_noob, the main question to me is: why do you read comments, but not edit history? Perhaps this could be improved? Is there anything that we can do? The problem is that while some newbies might find it useful, it may be distracting for some other as well as experts trying to solve the issue at hand.

Comment: What reason is there to think that a beginner ever *would* read the edit history?

Comment: @lpapp Now I would check the history for sure but when you're new it's not something you think of at first. Maybe when you're a new user (let say rep < x ) you could receive inbox all the detail about the edit. Instead of the standard an edit as been suggested [your post] it could be this + the messagethe editor left

Comment: @bluefeet *noisy and unnecessary* - totally agreed. Just like the comments that are automatically left while in the review queues.

Comment: @yuck the review queue comments are fine, the problem with them is they get repeated multiple times on the same post. Bombarding the user with multiple comments that are the same is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @GrantWinney: I always edit _all_ of my pet peeve issues.

Comment: @GrantWinney You're assuming a new user knows about the edit history and that the person editing left a useful/clarifying edit summary.

Comment: Can we make anything to make the edit explanation "more obvious"?

Comment: @GrantWinney The person leaving a comment after editing most likely will also have left a clear edit summary; the reverse is - unfortunately - not necessarily true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's unnecessary to do so.

Retaining a structured discussion without "noise" to drive the question towards a resolve far outweighs any benefit from teaching a user about not using signatures, pointless pleasantries, etc.

Users should have read the help section and already know such things.
I know, they don't read it, but is a user really going to take notice of your comment if they didn't read the help section, and/or didn't spend some time on the site learning enough to know simple things like no sigs?

If they're of the mindset to take note of a comment advising of no signatures (etc), then they'll learn just the same by their signature being removed from their post.

Comment: Sorry, disagree. I avoid any _discussion_ about "noise", but a single comment to inform the user, once, about "noise" has value beyond the individual post. That's what some don't seem to see. It's not just one post - it's all the other posts this user may make in the future, and all the posts yet to be made by the other users who may read the comment.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I have seen fruitless discussions when people disagreed, and there will be always some. It forms itself into a non-comprehensive comment wall about distracted argument vs. useful information. If anything, in _my_ opinion, it would be better to teach them about the edit summary in your comment rather than "casual fun". But I think this should be taught upfront rather than as a remedy when the issue has already been born. Sure, we may respectfully disagree, but that is fine. Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: I don't discuss the issue. I generally send one comment. If there is disagreement, I might reply to point out the link to the [meta] article, in case the OP didn't realize it was something he should read. That's about all, and it's rare that I have to go that far. Most are like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380211/converting-latin-characters-to-hebrew-encoding?noredirect=1#comment43361038_27380211

Comment: @JohnSaunders While it can be argued your comment you linked to was informative (and helping others commendable etc), the user responded too, so now 2 comments pollute the discussion space which should be for assisting with the question problem. Do you not think the user is above an IQ of 10 and so will likely "get it" from such things being removed from their post and their not seeing it elsewhere? I personally think it's pretty clear from spending an hour on Stack that it's not forum with "howdy all, how are you all" and "help me please/ ok thanks bye".

Comment: @James: so, delete the "pollution" if you like.

Answer (score 31):

I don't say that we *need* to leave such comments. However, I almost always leave a comment like that for low-rep users, if the question (or answer) is recent enough for them to benefit from.

Stack Exchange is a different model than most other Q&A sites or discussion forums. A user who is new to our sites can be expected to not know the ways in which these sites are different. I feel that by telling them up front, I improve the site by "teaching them how to fish". Their subsequent posts are less likely to require such cleanup if I tell them about the cleanup I performed on their *first* post.

I use the "[AutoReview Comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)" script, and post comments like these:

> Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

In fact, I just did: "[How can I sort a VBA MatchCollection by value of SubMatches(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27452798/how-can-i-sort-a-vba-matchcollection-by-value-of-submatchesn)".

The usual response I get from a comment like that is "thanks, I didn't know that; I'll keep it in mind for the future". That's exactly the outcome desired.

---

P.S. I expect most beginners don't even know there *is* an edit history. The link says "edit" - it doesn't say "click here to see the history of edits people have made to your post".

Comment: Thank you for sharing that auto review link, I always wondered how you did those so quickly.  I just assumed you were awesome. ;)

Comment: @paqogomez: "That, too".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not doubt that it may be useful at times, but these are my issues with it:1) It is distracting the discussion in comments about getting a solution for the question. I have the impression getting a solution would be more important than chat about such nuances. 2) Many times, OPs abandon questions and/or they do not learn from comments either. 3) Is it not trivial 99% from the edit type even without the edit summary that it is not needed in questions? 4) Even if it is (rarely?) useful, sometimes I see such comments unremoved over a long period of time.

Comment: It's not just a question of whether the comment is useful to the OP. It's also a question of whether the effect of the comment is useful to the site.

Comment: But you also have to consider that hundreds or thousands of other users might also view the question, as they have the same issue. And they do not care about such comments, they want help with their issue. So in that sense, it's noise and not useful for the Q&A as a whole. I also wonder if it's pointless. If user cares to read your comment, they will surely just understand without the need of the comment by it being removed from their question. How many times have you seen "Hey, why was my *thanks in advance* removed from my question"?

Comment: @James: do you assume that I'm incapable of judging from the evidence that I have seen? I have been a user here for going on six years now. You should assume that I _have_ considered it, and that I have decided it's a good idea. I started doing it quite a while ago, and I believe that it has helped. It's possible that you have only experienced the site as it has been since I started making such comments, in which case you have no basis to judge how things would have been if I had not made the comments.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at. I should give you some benefit of the doubt because you have high rep? Rep does not mean intelligence. I don't disagree that your friendly comments help others to learn, I just disagree that comments should be used to teach users to learn. That's what the help section is for, and the edit history, and their learning by being on the site. That's three places they can learn, and so I don't think polluting comments is necessary as they should be for assisting with the question.

Comment: "It's possible that you have only experienced the site as it has been since I started making such comments, in which case you have no basis to judge how things would have been if I had not made the comments" What? People often study and judge historical events. It doesn't take 122k rep or 6 years to understand simple things, like discussing trivial things in comments, which users should already know, is just noise and distracts from the actual goal - helping them with their issue. Your last example link even has the OP saying "Thanks, what about my question"...

Comment: Again, you either assume I don't see the same facts that you see, or you don't respect my assessment of those facts. And I haven't said anything about rep. I said I have had more time to observe than you have, and that I have seen the site change over that time. You refer to the help section and the edit history and learning by being on the site. Those things all existed before the users made the posts that I have commented on, and they clearly were not adequate. Some users learn from those things, others from being told directly and in a timely manner.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Again, I agree with you. But the world is not grey, it's multi coloured. Your comments can be helpful, stop users from doing such things again, educated those users and inform them of the ways of Stack, etc. But none of that means *they are therefore* not noise and polluting the space which is better used for discussing the problem at hand.